# select a file from pop up window

Tags: excel, vba, filedialog

I change the column name inside a cell. I do with help of Split function. But many of you have realized when there is already a formula inside cell, and it is referencing another excel file the pop up window appears.
What I try to do, not to select manually every time as inside rows and many sheets formulas have been changed to select a file and click open. I want also macro to do it for me. I tried filedialog object. Filedialog object has Show method and -1 is something that I need. But I cannot assign -1 to show method error gives "left side cannot be assigned to a value..."

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogPicker)

With fd
.Show = -1 ' error giving line
.Title = "Choose an Excel File"
.InitialFileName = "C:\Desktop\FolderMy\excelfile1.xlsm"
End With
```

The code above is inside For each loop. Which loops through every row in a given range and across worksheets.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Workbooks("excelfile1.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("C:C")
For rng in Workbooks("excelfile1.xlsm").Worksheet
---/
Next rng
```

The code of loop is examplification, it works perfect on my actual procedure. I need a clarification if I can write a macro( meaning by using filedialog object, show -1 method) not to select everytime the file and click Ok or Open.

Formula inside cell; "='C:\Desktop\FodlerMy[excelfile.xlsm]'Sheet1!$F$43
I use Split function with "$" to split the formula into three parts. I only change the array(1) (as (0) and (2) are same), I change the column name from F to G  then combine the arrays and string with help of "&" and put the string into the row

Comment: Are you just trying to [`ChangeLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink)?

Comment: No no. But that's useful for me. I did not know. Here I do not need it. Let me edit, and tell a little bit about formula inside cell.

Comment: You can't assign a value to the `.Show` method, it only returns a value (either `0` or `-1`) depending on if the user clicks **Cancel** or **OK** - [FileDialog.Show method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.show)

Comment: Does it mean, I have to click everytime . And that means not to able to automate executing -1 via macro?